# Listen to UDP broadcast with Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, udp

I'm really new to the whole UDP concept, so I'm sorry If I say something stupid.

I want my app that runs on Android only to listen for UDP broadcasts.

I installed this plugin [Cordova Chrome UDP](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp)

So my problem starts with that question:

If I want only to listen for messages do I have to create a socket or I just have to add listener like that:

`chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(receiveListener);`

Maybe I have to create a socket first so it will know where to listen for broadcasts?

And is there an easy way to test the connection. I tried several things one of which was to connect one of the devices to the other's hotspot. Then I tried to send broadcast signal from one of the devices (after using `setBroadcast` to enable the broadcast of the socket) but the other didn't receive it. The `onReceive` event actually fired but only on the device which sent the broadcast message (which is pretty obvious but I don't know if that could be a good news so I mention it).

Here is some code :

```
function sendBroadcast() {
    console.log("Sending broadcast");
    var port = 1667;
    var arr = new Uint8Array(256);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = i;
    }

    chrome.sockets.udp.create(function(createInfo) {
      chrome.sockets.udp.bind(createInfo.socketId, '0.0.0.0', port, function(result) {
        chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast(createInfo.socketId, true, function(result){
          chrome.sockets.udp.send(createInfo.socketId, arr.buffer, '255.255.255.255', port, function(result) {
            if (result < 0) {
              chrome.sockets.udp.close(createInfo.socketId);
            } else {
              chrome.sockets.udp.close(createInfo.socketId);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
}

function createSocket(){
    chrome.sockets.udp.create(function(createInfo) {
      chrome.sockets.udp.bind(createInfo.socketId, '0.0.0.0', 0, function(result) {
        chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast(createInfo.socketId, true, function(result){
             console.log("The socket with id: " + createInfo.socketId + " is created");
        });
      });
    });
}
```

On both devices I first call `createSocket()` and then from one of them I call `sendBroadcast()` but nothing is received on the other device.